# Вывести поля каждой структуры на экран?

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

В бинарном файле записано N структур. Как работать с данными структурами - например вывести поля каждой структуры на экран?
Структура:

```
struct Session
{
    char userName[24];
    int points;
};
```

Заполняем структуру:

```
void CreateSession()
{
    Session temp;
    printf_S("\nEnter your name: ");
    gets_s(temp.userName);
    temp.points = 0;
    SaveSessionToFile(temp);
}
```

Сохраняем в файл:

```
void SaveSessionToFile(Session temp)
{
    ofstream fout("AppData/Sessions", ios_base::binary | ios_base::app);
    fout.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(Session));
    fout.close();
}
```

Работает отлично - новые данные добавляются в конец бинарного файла. Но вот никак не могу понять как мне теперь работать с файлом - напимер сделать вывод данных каждой структуры? Например:

```
userName1 + points1 // Данные 1 структуры записать в string, вывести string;
userName2 + points2 // Данные 2 структуры записать в string, вывести string;
userName3 + points3 // Данные 3 структуры записать в string, вывести string;
```

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Вам уже ответили, я добавлю только - 1. незачем передавать по значению `void SaveSessionToFile(Session temp)`, передавайте как константную ссылку `void SaveSessionToFile(const Session& temp)`, и 2. учтите, что так сработает для простейших структур в духе C - так называемых POD - plain old data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно так же, как и записывали. Создаете входной файловый поток в бинарном режиме и записываете в экземпляр структуры.

```
Session s;

std::ifstream fin("Sessions", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

while (fin.peek() != EOF)
{
    fin.read((char*)&s, sizeof(Session));
    std::cout << s.userName << " " << s.points << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Только нужно учесть, что в общем случае это непереносимо, т..к выравнивание в разных компиляторах, на разных архтектурах может разниться. Поэтому, так можно делать лишь тогда, когда и запись и чтение производится с помощью программы, скомпилированной одним и тем же компилятором(либо же полностью совместимыми)

Comment: TheNorthon, спасибо Вам огромное, то что надо!